# What's up with CHECK and INIT blocks?

Tags: perl, include, circular-dependency

I have a circular dependency problem with Perl modules: say package `X` uses `Y` and wants to hold a static reference to an `Y` instance, and package `Y` uses `X` and wants to hold a static reference to an `X` instance.

Simply saying `our $x_instance = new X` will give *Can't locate object method "new"* in the module that was not loaded first.

I figured something like

```
our $x_instance;
INIT { $x_instance = new X }
```

would make sense, so I read [everything about the specially named blocks.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN,-UNITCHECK,-CHECK,-INIT-and-END)

Well, this works in a simple test I made, but in my real application it systematically shows *Too late to run INIT block.* The same happens with `CHECK` blocks.

The only explanation I found was from [Perl Monks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=348348) and I'm afraid I couldn't make much sense of it.

Does someone have an explanation about how Perl goes about executing `CHECK` and `INIT` block that goes beyond what is in `perlmod`, and would help me understand why my blocks and sometimes executed and sometimes not?

By the way, I just want to understand this—I am not specifically asking a solution to my original circular dependency problem, as I have a workaround that I am reasonably happy about:

```
our $x_instance;
sub get_x_instance {
    $x_instance //= new X;
    return $x_instance;
}
```

Comment: To answer your question an important key information is missing: since your approach works with INIT, we need information about your "real application" and its environment... are you `eval`utating parts of your code?

Comment: What version of Perl are you using?

Comment: @deviolog, I don't use `eval` but I use `do`. Changing all `do`'s for `require`'s changed nothing though. I load many CPAN modules, though. Is there a relation between the way `perl` works with `INIT` and the use of `eval`?

Comment: @scozy ... ^_^ you told us you read "[everything about the specially named blocks](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN,-UNITCHECK,-CHECK,-INIT-and-END)". Please have a look at that document again : )

Comment: @deviolog, What exactly do you want me to look at? In case it's the pagraph about `INIT` blocks *inside* code compiled by `require` et al., it's not relevant, my `INIT` blocks are in packages imported with `use`.

Comment: @scozy: There *must* be somwhere that you include a module at run time that contains `INIT`. Look again: it shouldn't be difficult. The error message will tell you which module is being compiled, and it should be a simple text search after that.

Comment: @Borodin, Damn it, the heart of the modules that I am working on itself is `require`'d at runtime because it uses `Inline::Java` and is in a forking server. I knew this, but it is so removed from the aspects I am working on right now that I had totally forgotten. Sorry for making you lose your time!

Comment: @scozy: No worries. I'm glad you found the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`INIT` blocks are executed immediately before the run time phase is started in the order the compiler encountered them during the compilation phase.

If you use use `require` (or `do`) at run time to compile a Perl file that includes an `INIT` block then the block won't be executed.

It is rare that there is a real reason to use `require` in preference to `use`.

Despite your confidence, there *must* be a place where you are attempting to load a module at run time that contains an `INIT` block. I suggest you install and use [`Carp::Always`](https://metacpan.org/module/Carp%3a%3aAlways) so that the `Too late to run INIT block` message is accompanied by a stack backtrace that will help you find the erroneous call.